How do I store the output of a lang chain pandas dataframe agent to a variable?
I am currently using two data frames and I wish to compare two columns across them, and then create an output variable. However, I want to store the output in the form of a pandas dataframe, or atleast in a json output, which I can then read back to python. My approach is currently using a python dataframe agent, if there's an alternative, would appreciate it.
My datasets look like this
Table 1
| ID  | Food items |
| --- | -----------|
| 1   | Apple      |
| 2   | Celery     |
| 3   | Chicken    |


Table 2
| ID  | Categories |
| ----| -----------|
| 1   | Vegetable  |
| 2   |Fruit       |
| 3   |Meat        |

I would like a mapping of Apple to Fruit, Celery to Vegetable etc in a table format.

Can you give an example of the input data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Have added it now in the question

Well, you need to create rules for such mapping, there's no pandas functionality you can use to linguistically match words.

I wanted to use the langchain functionality to be able to linguistically match the words.

When the output is generated, store it to a variable which will be in the form of a python dictionary of input and output.
For example if your output is in the format,
 input:{query}, output :{"Apple":"Fruit"} 

Then, save it to a variable
code_response=input:{query}, output :{"Apple":"Fruit"}

From this dictionary, you can extract output as code
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns=['Item','Category']) in your standard python dictionary manipulation.

It could be great if you add an example code for anyone wondering how you applied this anwer

With Pandas:
# Assuming your dataframes are named df1 and df2
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')

# If you want to just keep the Food items and Categories columns:
result = result[['Food items', 'Categories']]

